# Crystal Reports does not put linked view into FROM clause causing "The multi-part identifier xxx could not be bound"

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports-2008

I've stuck with Crystal Reports 2008 (12.0.0.683) project.

I have just added one more view in Database Expert to existing (working) report. It's (the view) linked with main table. It's linked as Left Outer Join (Not Enforced, =).

On runtime it sends a query to SQL Server where column from the additional view are put into SELECT clause but the view name is not put into FROM clause. It causes "The multi-part identifier xxx could not be bound" error. I understend what the error is all about but I cannot force CR to use my view in FROM clause. I do not think there is any special about the view (more views are already linked in this report).

Did you face with similar problem? Please give any tips.
Thanks in advance!

PS. A query that goes to SQL Server (seen with SQL Profiler) is like:

```
SELECT
  newview.col1,
  newview.col2,
  maintable.col1,
  maintable.col2,
  subtable.col1,
  subtable.col2
FROM -- no [newview] anywhere in FROM clase
  maintable
  INNER JOIN
  subtable
  ON (.. = ..)
WHERE
  .. = ..
```

Comment: also INNER JOIN not INNER JOINT

Comment: it was only my misspell - corrected, thx

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found solution. There is "Show SQL Query.." in Crystal Reports apps. In query view I've found that one of tables is taken from another database (test db instead of production one). That table was not my view that I was having problem to access. And one more: Database Expert was showing in properties that all tables comes from only one DB.

After I manage to set location of that table to be taken from same DB - the problem with accessing view was also fixed - its name is in FROM clause now.

Shame on you Crystal Reports, shame on you..